# Addition of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

If I have two linear maps $ T : R^2 → R^2$ and $S : R^3 → R^3$ then $(T+S)(v) = T(v) + S(v)$ but in this case that wouldn't be defined right? The addition of linear maps is only defined when both the maps have the same domain and codomain is this correct? Because like in this case T+S just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You're right. The two maps must have the same domain and codomain.

Comment: Correct: $T(v)+S(v)$ doesn't make sense since $T(v)$ and $S(v)$ are not in the same set, and thus $T+S$ doesn't make sense. Now if somebody wanted to introduce a further map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^3$ that sent $(x,y)$ to $(x,y,0)$, thus identifying $\Bbb R^2$ with a subset of $\Bbb R^3$, then suitably combining $T$ with this map might yield a linear map that could be added to $S$. Some sources might do that implicitly.

Comment: Wait so you're saying if I have a map say $ Q : R^2 →R^3$ I would be able to add this map to T? Or did I misunderstand because that still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @safelisdt Note that there is a difference between a composition of functions and adding them together. In your case, you could not add $Q$ and $T$ together because they they have different inputs (2d vs 3d vectors). However, you could compose the functions (ie T(Q(v)) where v is a vector in $R^2$.